# Cannot Click Parallax Footer due to Canvas

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, parallax

I'm modifying a theme for shopify and have run into a slight error.
((https://markslights.co.uk/collections/collection-one))

As you can see when you visit the URL, the footer setup is paralax, meaning once you reach the bottom it fades in slowly. The issue that is currently present is that it's impossible to click anything in the footer as the web page thinks you're interactive with the canvas (When you click more lines get added to the background) I've done a bit of research and looked into the z-index, however, modifying the z-index on my footer makes the footer none parallax anymore. I was wondering if it was to do with the "fixed" position type of the canvas I had a play around to no avail.

Could somebody please point me in the right direction

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use the dev tools you can see that its because the canvas is overlapping the footer. this can be fixed by setting canvas `margin-bottom: -footer height`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, setting a margin on the canvas didn't actually add a margin.

Comment: @AdamM i am looking at it now, can you post the css for the website?

Comment: @AdamM use this #particles-js {
    pointer-events: none;
}

Comment: Amazing! I shouldn't thought to do this from the start - I guess I don't really care to much about it being interactive.. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. Unfortunately there are too many players at play inside that document. It was next to impossible of overwriting styles as there were multiple css files and styling inside the html. If not i think we should’ve gotten it to work with the interactive stuff. Anyhow. Have a great day @AdamM